# Can we add dependencies in POM.xml file using commands in terminal in Springboot..?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Adding dependencies in POM.xml file using terminal..?

While working in Springboot I have added dependencies in POM.xml manually,when i am  working some annotations have to add while working I have to add it automatically using terminal commands.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Yes you can.</strike>

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>`

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Edit: I did not understand what you want to do (Thank you to the comment). If you want add a dependency using the terminal, currently not exist a command from maven to do that. You could made a script to include the text in your pom, but still something you need elaborate by yourself. So the sort answer is "no, you can't"

Comment: That is not what he asked. He wants a command to add dependencies to the maven `pom.xml`. Not to install dependencies into the local repository.